# Emplace back thread on vector

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

Why this cause undefined behavior?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::thread> threads(3);

void task() { std::cout<<"Alive\n";}
void spawn() {
        for(int i=0; i<threads.size(); ++i)
                //threads[i] = std::thread(task);
                threads.emplace_back(std::thread(task));

        for(int i=0; i<threads.size(); ++i)
                threads[i].join();
}

int main() {
        spawn();
}
```

If I will create threads as in commented line thread is copied/moved assignment so its fine, but why is not working when creating thread in place?

Comment: Please be more specific about "not working" and "undefined behavior".
Also, to create object in-place (i.e. totally elliding copy), you should do threads.emplace_back(task).

Comment: The threads you are attempting to join aren't joinable. The general advice for C++, as always, is that before you do anything more complicated, make sure you *fully understand* `int` and `std::vector<int>`. Don't move on until those are both completely clear to you, and whenever you have a problem, first reduce it to either `int` or `std::vector<int>`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What is happening in your code is that you construct three default threads, then add three further threads.

Change:

```
std::vector<std::thread> threads(3);
```

To:

```
std::vector<std::thread> threads;
const size_t number_of_threads = 3;

int main() {
    threads.reserve(number_of_threads);
    spawn();
}
```

And inside `spawn`:

```
void spawn() {
    for (int i = 0; i < number_of_threads; ++i) {
        threads.emplace_back(std::thread(task));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < threads.size(); ++i) {
        threads[i].join();
    }
}
```

When you are using `emplace_back` or `push_back`, you must not allocate the memory before, because that will call the constructor of threads. You should just `reserve` it.

BTW, since you are using `emplace_back` not `push_back` you can directly write:

```
threads.emplace_back(task);
```

Comment: Note that even though you've reserved capacity, threads.size() still returns 0 - and threads.capacity() may return any number >= 3.  So the first loop in spawn() needs to use the same value (preferably the same variable or constant) passed to reserve().  And in this specific case, there's probably nothing to gain from calling reserve() at all.

Comment: You are right about the first part that I missed. But there is indeed gain from using reserve which is denying re-allocation that may happen.

Comment: Only if the implementation grows the vector in increments smaller than the size you reserve - which in this specific case is highly unlikely.

Comment: *What is happening in your code is that you construct three default threads, then add three further threads.* It's worse than that, actually. Note the for loop's header: `for (int i=0; i<threads.size(); ++i)`. As new items are added to `threads`, `threads.size()` gets larger and larger, and the loop exit condition is not going to be ever met. You'll sooner run off the ability to create a new thread.