# How to start several threads in C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have some class objects and want to hand them over to several threads. The number of threads is given by the command line.

When I write it the following way, it works fine:

```
thread t1(thread(thread(tasks[0], parts[0])));
thread t2(thread(thread(tasks[1], parts[1])));
thread t3(thread(thread(tasks[2], parts[2])));
thread t4(thread(thread(tasks[3], parts[3])));
t1.join();
t2.join();
t3.join();
t4.join();
```

But as I mentioned, the number of threads shall be given by the command line, so it must be more dynamic. I tried the following code, which doesn't work, and I have no idea what is wrong with it:

```
for(size_t i=0; i < threads.size(); i++) {
    threads.push_back(thread(tasks[i], parts[i]));
}
for(auto &t : threads) {
    t.join();
}
```

I hope someone has an idea on how to correct it.

Comment: "Doesn't work" doesn't help us. Do you get a specific error?

Comment: side note: `thread t1(thread(thread(...` seems a bit redundant, no?

Answer (score 4):

In this statement:

```cpp
thread t1(thread(thread(tasks[0], parts[0])));
```

You don't need to move a thread into another thread and then move that into another thread.  Just pass your task parameters directly to `t1`'s constructor:

```
thread t1(tasks[0], parts[0]);
```

Same with `t2`, `t3`, and `t4`.

---

As for your loop:

```
for(size_t i=0; i < threads.size(); i++) {
    threads.push_back(thread(tasks[i], parts[i]));
}
```

Assuming you are using `std::vector<std::thread> threads`, then your loop is populating `threads` wrong.  At best, the loop simply won't do anything at all if `threads` is initially empty, because `i < threads.size()` will be false when `size()==0`.  At worst, if `threads` is not initially empty then the loop will run and continuously increase `threads.size()` with each call to `threads.push_back()`, causing an endless loop because `i < threads.size()` will never be false, thus pushing more and more threads into `threads` until memory blows up.

Try something more like this instead:

```cpp
size_t numThreads = ...; // taken from cmd line...
std::vector<std::thread> threads(numThreads);

for(size_t i = 0; i < numThreads; i++) {
    threads[i] = std::thread(tasks[i], parts[i]);
}
for(auto &t : threads) {
    t.join();
}
```

Or this:

```cpp
size_t numThreads = ...; // taken from cmd line...
std::vector<std::thread> threads;
threads.reserve(numThreads);

for(size_t i = 0; i < numThreads; i++) {
    threads.emplace_back(tasks[i], parts[i]);
}
for(auto &t : threads) {
    t.join();
}
```

Comment: Your first suggestion works perfectly fine. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Threads are not copyable; try this:

```
threads.emplace_back(std::thread(task));
```

[Emplace back thread on vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39266461/emplace-back-thread-on-vector)